# How to create a conditional rendering of Gatsby's Link component and <a> tag for links?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, gatsby

From Gatsby's official docs regarding Gatsby's Link component, it states that the Link component is used only for internal links, whereas for external links, one has to use the  tag.

I'm building a Button component that has inbuilt props for links. The problem is right now I have to create 2 separate Button components for internal and external links due to the limitation.

**My goal is to use one `freeLink` component that can be used as both internal and external links**

I've tried creating a subcomponent (`Button`) for the button, but I'm unsure of the parent component (`freeLink`) which requires conditional rendering. The subcomponent is as of follows:

```
const Button = props => (
    <button className={props.btnType}>
        <span>{props.text}</span>
    </button>
)
```

This is the visual logic to what I want to achieve:

1. For Internal links

```
<freeLink intLink="/about" btnType="btn-cta" text="Read about us">
</freeLink>

...which will render...

<Link to="/about">
    <button className="btn-cta">
        <span>Read about us</span>
    </button>
</Link>
```

2. It is relatively similar for external links

```
<freeLink extLink="https://google.com" btnType="btn-cta" text="Visit Our Partner">
</freeLink>

...which will render...

<a href="https://google.com">
    <button className="btn-cta">
        <span>Visit Our Partner</span>
    </button>
</a>
```

I'm quite new to Javascript, Gatsby and React so I'm unsure to how to apply a conditional rendering based on props applied.

Any advice, suggestion, or direction to how to code up the `freeLink` component is greatly appreciated.

P.S: I've seen [Conditionally Use Gatsby Link in React Compoment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56530862/conditionally-use-gatsby-link-in-react-compoment) but the chosen answer is too complicated for me to understand, and I don't have enough points to comment to ask for further elaboration.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something simple like this:

```
const MyLink = (href, text, ...props) => {
  if (href.startsWith("http") { 
    return <a href={href} {...props}>{text}</a>
  } else { 
    return <Link href={href} {...props}>{text}</Link>
  }
}
```

Comment: I’m sorry for this stupid question, but what does `...props` do? Also, in place of `{text}`, is it possible to add a child component (`Button`) consisting of props? And if so, how do I access those props from the parent component (in your case, `MyLink`)?

Comment: `...props` just means "give me the rest of the props". Yes, you could use render any component in there, e.g. `<Button>{text}</Button>` if you wanted to. In that case you could pass down the props: `<Button {...props }>{text}</Button>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your component could return different stuff based on weather you pass it a `to` or a `href` prop:

```
import { Link } from "gatsby"

const freeLink = props => {
  if (props.to) return <Link {...props} />
  return <a {...props} />
}`
```